# Pull Wordpress data outside the Wordpress domain

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website that I recently added a Wordpress blog to.

`www.mydomain.com/blog/` it is in its own *new* directory.

That seems to work fine and I can navigate to it and do all the Wordpress stuff.

But I want include the top 3 posts (or insert whatever from Wordpress here) on my initial *index.php* page (or other php pages).

`www.mydomain.com/index.php`

I have tried adding `<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>` but that doesn't seem to work and throws errors.

I know my **index.php** doesn't "*technically*" know about Wordpress, so it makes sense it would fail.

So my question is: ***What do I include in a non-Wordpress page so that I can pull posts?***

I don't really know how to ask google, since "*include wordpress post in php page*" just shows you how to in the realm of Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

You have to access the wordpress database where you can get all posts of wordpress

```
$wpdb2 = new wpdb('dbuser', 'dbpassword', 'dbname', 'dbhost');

    // get 10 posts, assuming the other WordPress db table prefix is "wp_"
    $query = "SELECT post_title, guid FROM wp_posts
              WHERE post_status = 'publish'
               AND post_type = 'post'
              ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 10";

    $someposts = $wpdb2->get_results($query, OBJECT);
    foreach($someposts as $somepost)
      echo "<a href=\"{$somepost->guid}\">{$somepost->post_title}</a><br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of connecting to the WordPress database directly, you could also utilize your WordPress feed.

```
$context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
$url = 'http://www.example.com/blog/feed';

$xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
if (isset($xml->channel->item)) 
{
    foreach($xml->channel->item as $item) 
    {
      echo $item->title;
    }
}
```